# How can i make Selection sort of a 2D List

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, selection-sort

```
#P = number of Posts P[i][j].timestamp -> where i Person and j the Posting and the timestamp 
#N = Number of posts we need (the length for the loops)
# Implement your algorithm . Dont use sorted or sort. Sort by timestamp
def Sort(P, N):

    for number_post in range(N):

      # Find the lowest Date in List
        person = number_post
        j = number_post

        for i in range(number_post+1, N):
            if P[person][j].timestamp > P[person][i].timestamp:
                    person = i

       # If lower swap the Elements in List       
            temp = P[person][number_post].timestamp
            P[person][number_post].timestamp = P[person][i].timestamp
            P[person][i].timestamp = temp
    #Einfügen in den Newsfeed
            S[N] = temp

    #S = [P[0][0], P[1][0],  P[1][1]]

    # TODO end
    return S
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I tried to loop over all Elements but i got an error that i cant set attribute. I'm new to Python and i have to use it. but i dont know how to make these seleton Sort with a List in a List where we can access the Timestamp by .timestamp for example P[i][j].timestamp